# Sync prop with the parent in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to have a bidirectional property between a component and its child. In this example, I have a  shared string which is sent to my sub-components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <foobar title="Foo" :value.sync="shared"></foobar>
    <foobar title="Bar" :value.sync="shared"></foobar>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import Sub from './sub'

export default {
  components: {
    'foobar': Sub
  },
  watch : {
    shared() {
      console.log("Shared value was updated")
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      shared: "Content"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Each subcomponent is just a text input bound to this shared property:

```
<template>
  <b-form-group :description="title">
    <b-form-input v-model="value"></b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: String,
    title: String
  }
}
</script>
```

The expected behaviour is to always see the same value in both text input. If I modify `Foo`, `Bar` is updated and the watcher would trig the event `Shared value was updated`.

I get the error instead:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten 
whenever the parent component re-enters.
```

Comment: You cant mutate a prop and expect the value in parent to change (unless you're changing a property of an object), the correct way is to $emit in child to send the updated data to parent and in parent use v-on to update data.

Comment: @ChrisLi Is it possible to take advantage of `.sync`?

Comment: there isn't much difference between .sync and v-model, .sync can allow you to two way bind using props other than 'value' but you still need to $emit the event in your child component.

Comment: @ChrisLi Yep and that's the reason there is no `sync` in Vue 3. Instead you can have multiple `v-model`s synchronizing multiple props...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit event in your child component.

I didn't test this code but it should look something like this.

```
<template>
  <b-form-group :description="title">
    <b-form-input :value="value" @input="$emit('update:value', $event.target.value)"></b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: String,
    title: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: just can emit the some value: `@input="$emit('update:value', value)`

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo No you cant do that. You are just emitting `value` from internal state but that `value` is not updated by `b-form-input` because there is no `v-model`. `$event.target.value` is necessary...

Comment: just try it and tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can make your fooBar component to handle prop as a v-model

```
<foobar title="Foo" v-model:value="shared"></foobar>
```

Additional documentation available [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#v-model-arguments)